# WCF Facility and Configuring Service Endpoint Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, wcf-binding

Im having some issues configuring the Service side of my WCF -> MVC3 Solution.

The configuration is as follows:

```
.Register(
      Component.For<IFileDownloadService>()
         .ImplementedBy<FileDownloadService>()
         .Named("FileDownloadService")
         .AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel()
              .Hosted()
              .PublishMetadata(x => x.EnableHttpGet())
              .AddEndpoints(
                    WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding
                         {
                              TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
                         })
                    )
              ))
```

However the WCFTestClient shows me that generated config is:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the direction of resolving why the TransferMode remains Buffered? 
In actuality I want to configure a number of other settings for this endpoint but I thought I'd keep it simple to start.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tested it by changing the client config to what you expect to see if it does actually work?  Reason: I am wondering if it is just that the service client is not able to infer these values - this is an interesting read that kind of implies that may be possible:  [Generating the client config](http://books.google.at/books?id=PvNrurEhmiEC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=svcutil+infer+config&source=bl&ots=ChAnMsMWKx&sig=dy85gZLDfJJsO20TxNeQRH2Ti1I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=55XpT72OHdSL4gSQmOmLDg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=svcutil%20infer%20config&f=false)

Comment: @kmp, Indeed! I have, as per my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138460/another-the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-400-bad-request. As far as I am now aware the Test client infers the default values for the binding, however my service still remains in error as per the other question. This particular question is seemingly a non-starter. Thanks for replying though.